# can someone explain me how does this function work?

Tags: javascript, callback

Heyhey everyone!!

Can someone, please, explain me this function and its callback function.. How does the thing work here?

```
    function generate(n){
     for(var i = 0; i<n; i++){
            generate(n-1);
            console.log(i + "," + n);
           }
      }

      generate(3)
```

And this is the output: 
0,1
0,2
0,1
1,3
0,3
0,1
0,2
0,1
0,2
1,2
1,3
0,1
0,2
0,1
0,2
0,1
2,3

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: The function calls itself - the search term you're looking for is *recursion*. For a better answer, you'll have to be more specific about what you want to know.

Comment: Callback? I doubt that

Comment: Ok. IanPudney, thank you. When I call generate function with the n=3, we go into the for loop and what happens there? What happens when we call generate(n-1)?

Comment: use pen and paper, this is simple recursion problem.

Answer (score 0):

So this is an example of recursion (I think of it like Inception).

When you first call the function generate(3) the code goes through the following steps:

1. `for(var i = 0; i<n; i++){
               generate(n-1); //Once it sees this line inside the loop it *calls itself* so the next step, since n-1 = 2,  the function generate(2) is executed inside the if loop within the first function call generate(3)`
2. In generate(2) we repeat the first step but with n=2 so the following code runs:

   `for(var i = 0; i<n; i++){
               generate(n-1); //n here is 2, so n-1 is 1. So the function calls itself again with the parameter 1. i.e generate(1)`

If at this point you think this will go on forever remember it will stop doing so once i = n in the if conditions.

3. In generate(1) the following code runs:

   `for(var i = 0; i<n; i++){
               generate(n-1); //generate(0) is called`
4. In generate(0), the if condition i<0 is not met because i= 0 and n= 0, so the function generate(0) does not call itself or return any values. This is the deepest we go in this recursion hole and we start climbing out.
5. The code will go back to generate(1) (*which called generate(0) and needs to finish its if loop*). The following line of code will run:

   `console.log(i + "," + n); //Prints out 0,1`

Now that this instance of generate() is complete we keep climbing out till the rest of the generate() that were called earlier are completed as well.

6. The code will go back to generate(2) and will print out 0,2

etc.

Hope that made it clearer!